Pandas counting the amount of True/False values in one column for a unique set/grouping of another column
I am trying to count and list unique values in a column based on another column's as long as the unique count is greater than 2. I was referencing this post, which has got me partially there, but need to understand how to filter UniqueNum further. (Ref: How to count unique values in one colulmn based on value in another column by group in Pandas)
key_id = {1008,1051,1003,1005,1072,1079,1092,1093,1004,2000}

(filtData.loc[(filtData['colC'] > 0) & (filtData['colB'].isin(key_id)),'colB']
    .groupby(filtData['colA'])
    .agg(UniqueNum='nunique')
    .reset_index())
# Above .loc might need additional booleans to include only uniqueNum greater than 2

Current Input:
           colA  colB       colC
0        1105904         1007   867.000000
1        1105904         1008    93.330002
2        1105904         2000     0.420000
3        1105904         1004     0.000000
4        1105904         1005     4.000000
5        1105905         1008     4.000000
6        1105905         1001     0.000000
7        1105905         1004     0.000000
8        1105905         1005     1.500000
9        1105905         1072     4.000000
10       1105905         1093     0.250000
11       1111111         1001     0.350000
12       1111111         1002     0.100000
13       1111111         1003     0.000000
14       1111111         1004     0.250000
15       1111111         1093     0.250000

Desired Output:
    colA    UniqueNum
0   1105904 3
1   1105905 4

# colA value 1111111 should not show up because the unique number count is not greater than 2. 

Once the desired output has been achieved, we want to put the unique values from colA into a set. Then, create a CSV with the filtered values where it includes colA, colB, colC where the criteria: colB values must be found in key_id, colC values are greater than 0, and the count of colB values included in key_id associated with colC values greater than 0 has a count greater than 2. I figure it might be an aggregation modification. As a side note, I'm fairly new to Pandas and learning more complex boolean indexing. Help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Can you please provide a [mre] of the input? (with all needed columns) and the matching expected output?

@mozway, I updated my original post to include example of the input. Maybe for this exercise the gt(0) can be set to gt(2) for now.

Thank you but please, rather than your full dataset with ..., please craft a small but meaningful example and provide the matching expected output. You can see the linked question as example of a good MRE (10-20 rows max, non-ambiguous, demonstrating the edge cases).

How do you list colB in your results? The structure of your groupby output doesn't make that possible? Unless you mean as a list?

@mozway and ifly6, see if my example helps clarify. I also updated my final goal if that changes the approach.

Your logic is correct, the easiest it to filter the rows after aggregation, for example using query:
key_id = {1008,1051,1003,1005,1072,1079,1092,1093,1004,2000}

(filtData.loc[(filtData['colC'] > 0) & (filtData['colB'].isin(key_id)),'colB']
    .groupby(filtData['colA'])
    .agg(UniqueNum='nunique')
    .reset_index()
    .query('UniqueNum > 2')
)

Or loc:
key_id = {1008,1051,1003,1005,1072,1079,1092,1093,1004,2000}

(filtData.loc[(filtData['colC'] > 0) & (filtData['colB'].isin(key_id)),'colB']
    .groupby(filtData['colA'])
    .agg(UniqueNum='nunique')
    .reset_index()
    .loc[lambda x: x['UniqueNum'] > 2]
)

Output:
      colA  UniqueNum
0  1105904          3
1  1105905          4


mozway, I might have prematurely marked this issue as resolved.
(filtData['colC'] > 0) & (filtData['colB'].isin(key_id)) seems to be independent of each other. Is there a way that the two comparisons be included as part of the same row evaluation?
